# Setting up a logout link properly

Tags: php, logout

Currently working a little Sign-Up/Login system with PHP. Here is the situation:

I have this first page named "signup.php" for signing up and logging in. Once you submit your form, you are redirected to a second page called "diary.php". Once you click the submit button, a session is created respectively with your id within the "users" database. Without the diary.php, there's a logout link.
If you signed up or logged in and you are now viewing diary.php, you cannot view the signup.php page unless you press logout. Once you press logout, you are redirected to the signup.php page, but with a logout variable in the $_GET array.

```
<a href='signup.php?logout=1'>Logout</a>
```

I'm using this logout variable to check the moment there is a "logout" key exists in $_GET array, it destroys the session and redirects me back to the signup.php page.

Now here is the problem. Say I signed up for a new account, then logged out. Once I log out there's going to be a "logout" key within the GET, right? (to destroy session). If I try to sign up for another account, it actually is going to sign up me (on the database), but it automatically logs out for me since I had the logout key in my link and also because there was no session (I have in my code few lines that automatically take you back to signup.php if there is no session).

I hope that was enough to make it clear for you all. I'm going to leave the code for my two pages for you to examine. Thank you!

- signup.php

  ```
  session_start();

   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","diary");


   $error = '';
   $success = '';

  if (array_key_exists("submit",$_POST)) {
      if (!$_POST['email']) {
          $error.= "Email field is missing.<br>";
      }

      if (!$_POST["password"]) {
          $error .= "Password field is missing.<br>";
      }

      if ($error != '') {
          $error = "Fill in the missing field(s):<br>".$error;
      }

      else if ($_POST["submit"] == "Sign up") {
          $email = $_POST["email"];
          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email';";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
              $error .= "This account already exists!";
          } else {
              $email = $_POST["email"];
              $password = $_POST["password"];
              $query1 = "INSERT INTO users (email,password) VALUES ('$email','$password');";
              mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
              $success.= "Successfully signed up!";
              $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email';";
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$query));
              $id=$row["id"];
              $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
              header("Location: diary.php");

              if (!isset($_POST["signUpRemember"])) {
              } else {
                  setcookie("id",$id,time() + 60*60*24*30);
              }            
          }
      }  else if ($_POST["submit"] == "Login")  {

          $email = $_POST["email"];
          $password = $_POST["password"];
          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email';";
          if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,$query)) == 0) {
              $error.= "This account does not exist, sign up for a new account!";        
          } else {
              $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = '$email';";
              $rows = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$query));
              if ($password != $rows["password"]) {
                  $error.= "You have inserted the wrong password for this account. Please, try again!";
              } else {
                  $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email';";
                  $rows = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$query)); 
                  $_SESSION["id"] = $rows["id"];
                  if (!isset($_POST["signUpRemember"])) {
              } else {
                  setcookie("id",$rows["id"],time() + 60*60*24*30);
              }    
                  header("Location :diary.php");
              }

          }

      }
  }

   if (array_key_exists("logout",$_GET)) {

       unset($_SESSION["id"]);
       setcookie("id","",time() - 60*600);


   } 

  if (array_key_exists("id",$_SESSION)) {
      header("Location: diary.php");

  }

  ?>
  ```

  ```
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <title>Secret Diary</title>
        <style>

            body {
                margin:0;
                height: 0;
            }
            #error {
                background-color: red;
            }
            body {
                  background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
                  background-color: #cccccc;
              }

            #containerLogin {
                  margin: auto;
                  width: 30%;
                  padding: 10px;
                  margin-top: 5%;
            }

            #containerSignup {
                  margin: auto;
                  width: 30%;
                  padding: 10px;
                  margin-top: 5%;

            }


            .switchBtt {
                margin-top: 5%;
                width: 70%;
            }

            .display-4 {
                font-weight: 300;
            }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="error"><?php if ($error != "") { echo $error; } else { echo "<script>$( '#error' ).css('background-color', 'green');</script>"; echo $success;} ?></div>
        <div id="containerLogin">
         <center><h1 class="display-4 text-muted "><font color="#6D3E6C">Secret Diary</font></h1>
             <br>
                   <h5 class=" text-muted "><font color="#DFD2CA">Welcome back!</font></h5>
             <br>
       <form method="post" name="signup">
    <div class="form-group">


      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check ">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="checked" name="signUpRemember">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="signUpRemember">Keep me signed in</label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
   </form>
             <div  class="btn btn-secondary switchBtt">Switch to sign-up panel &#x21B9; </div>

      </center>

        </div>
              <div id="containerSignup">
         <center><h1 class="display-4 text-muted "><font color="#6D3E6C">Secret Diary</font></h1>
             <br>
                   <h5 class="text-muted "><font color="#DFD2CA">Sign up today, for free!</font></h5>
             <br>
       <form method="post" name="signup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check ">s
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="checked "name="LoginRemember">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="LoginRemember">Keep me signed in</label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign up" name="submit">
   </form>
             <div class="btn btn-secondary switchBtt">Switch to login panel &#x21B9; </div>

      </center>
        </div>

      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    </body>
      <script>
          $("#containerLogin").hide();
          $(".switchBtt").click (function () {
            $("#containerLogin").toggle();
            $("#containerSignup").toggle();
          });
      </script>
  </html>
  ```

  - diary.php

  ```
  session_start();

      if (array_key_exists("id",$_SESSION)) {
          echo "<p>Logged In! <a href='signup.php?logout=1'>Logout</a></p>";
          echo "<br>";
          echo $_SESSION["id"]."<br>";
      } else {
          header("Location: signup.php");
      }

      ?>
  ```

Comment: Long question, much useless html, but no clear question. Do you have a programmimg question or a concept question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally shouldn't be using GET query strings to change state in your application for pretty much this exact reason.

[GET requests are not supposed to have any side effects](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) and browsers will try to take advantage of this to speed up page loads by either pre-requesting pages before a user clicks on them or by caching a page and not actually requesting it from the server. Either of these cases will result in unexpected behavior. Also, if someone bookmarks the page with ?logout=1 on it they'll (probably accidentally) log themselves out any time they return to the page.

It'd be better to use the POST verb for this. You can easily do with with an HTML <form> tag and a submit button:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST" id="logout_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="logout" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

In your PHP you can detect if someone has hit the button by doing the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    //log user out
}
```

Comment: Your idea works a lot better. I decided to remove the code inside signup.php that logs the user out when there's a logout key within the GET array and move to the diary.php where the logout button is. Now for some reason, I'm not getting redirected back the signup page when I click the logout button. This is new code for the diary.php (https://ghostbin.com/paste/dkn2r)

Comment: Assuming you haven't written anything out yet you can always redirect the user after processing by using Header("Location: signup.php"); The caveat there is you have to do that before absolutely anything gets written to the client.

Comment: I have some code in signup.php that checks if there's a session or not. If there is, it automatically redirects you to the diary.php. I deleted that piece of code and tried clicking the button, and it actually worked. This now tells me that when I'm clicking the button, it actually doesn't unset the session for some reason which forces the code within the signup.php page to instantly redirect you back to diary.php (btw, I edited my previous comment, check it out. It has the diary.php code)

Comment: Never mind, it was the "action" attribute within the form that's causing the problem! For some reason, it just stops the session from unsetting. You can't even have it go hand in hand with the "header" function. I had to delete it  and keep the header function so that it works. Thank you anyway :) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is a good one (and accepted!), but at the moment where I work is going through an accessibility audit, so I have that on my mind. Screen readers, people who use high contrast custom style sheets, etc. can't deal with a form button as easily as plain text.

Also I've had issues in (old) PHP clearing sessions with `session_destroy`, so I loop through the session variables and `unset` them.

```
<a href="/logout.php">Log out</a>
```

And then logout.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

foreach($_SESSION as $sk=>$sv){
  unset($_SESSION[$sk]);
}

header("location: /");

?>
```

Comment: May I ask, what is the advantage of having the logout code separately in another page, then redirect to the main page once the code is executed?  Why not just run the logout code within the page that the logout button/link exist?